# Mysterious member "default" of type A1 => B1

Tags: scala, namespaces

Here is an odd situation, where a method argument name is apparently shadowed by another symbol (which one?) of type `A1 => B1`:

```
object OddBug extends scala.swing.Action(null) {
  def apply() = ()

  def foo(default: String): scala.swing.Component = {
    val res = new scala.swing.TextField(16)
    res.listenTo(res)
    res.reactions += {
      case scala.swing.event.EditDone(_) =>
        if (res.text.isEmpty) res.text = default  // !
    }
    res
  }
}
```

The compiler says:

```
[error]  ...: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : A1 => B1
[error]  required: String
[error]         if (res.text.isEmpty) res.text = default
[error]                                          ^
```

Is this a bug in the compiler (Scala 2.10.3)? Since I can refer to `default` outside the reaction, I suspect it is a problem with `PartialFunction`.

---

A workaround is as follows:

```
  def foo(default: String): scala.swing.Component = {
    val res = new scala.swing.TextField(16)
    res.listenTo(res)
    def fixDefault: String = default
    res.reactions += {
      case scala.swing.event.EditDone(_) =>
        if (res.text.isEmpty) res.text = fixDefault
    }
    res
  }
```

Comment: When the partial function literal is desugared your case code will end up in the `applyOrElse` method, which has a argument named `default`. You shouldn't have to know or think about that, though, so this definitely looks like a bug. At a glance I don't see anything relevant in the issue tracker.

Comment: By the way, this can be minimized to something like `{ case _ => default }: PartialFunction[Any, Any]`, which definitely shouldn't compile.

Comment: Ok, I will file a bug then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @travis-brown, this is probably a leakage from desugering the partial function literal. Submitted as [SI-8329](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8329).